# X and Y axis of browser

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried this code:

```
WebDriver f1=new FirefoxDriver();
f1.get("http://google.com/");
Point P=f1.manage().window().getPosition();
System.out.println(P);
System.out.println(P.getX());
System.out.println(P.getY());
```

But I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.openqa.selenium.Point to java.awt.Point

    at Inbox.XandYaxisofbrowser.main(XandYaxisofbrowser.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement is likely wrong.  Check to make sure you're importing **org.openqa.selenium.Point** and *not* **java.awt.Point**.

Comment: Sure  thing.  Please upvote and select this as the answer if it helped.  Thanks.

Comment: why have you edited your question completely now? Now my answer won't make sense for anyone experiencing the same issue.